# Recursively print a Node and its sucessors with toString

Tags: java, recursion

Taking into account Node.java:

```
public class Node {
  private int value;
  private ArrayList<Node> successors;
```

I want create a toString method that prints recursively the successors with its successors  and so on:

```
( A ) 
  -> ( B )
         -> ( C )
  -> ( D )
```

I cannot figure out how to add `\t` to the toString method to get the print:

```
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder successorsString = new StringBuilder();

    for (Node sucessor : this.successors  ) {
      successorsString.append("\n\t  ->"+ sucessor );
    }
    return "( " + this.value +" )" + successorsString;
  }
```

Comment: successorsString = successorsString.append("\n\t  ->"+ sucessor );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks very much like a graph/tree traversal problem. Looking at your expected output, it looks like DFS (Depth First Search) traversal would be the way to go.

The key point to note here is that as we move deeper, the number of \t increase. Hence there is a correlation between the depth and the number of \t to put.

One way to approach this would be to have a depth variable while recursing and then insert \t that many times to the result string before execution

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    toStringRec(this, 0, res);
    return res.toString();
}


 public static void toStringRec(Node node, int depth, StringBuilder result){
    if(node==null)
        return;

    // adding self to result
    result.append("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<depth; i++)
        result.append("\t");
    result.append(node.val);

    for (Node sucessor : node.successors  ) {
      toStringRec(sucessor, depth+1, result);
    }
}
```

Comment: it should be node.successors in the loop, or don't have the node parameter and just use this consistenlty

Comment: Also, declared return type is String but should be void for toStringRec

Comment: p.p.s: I usually hand in the in the indent as a string, so there is no need for a loop -- instead you can just do `result.append(indent)` and hand `indent + "\t"` to the recursion

Comment: p.p.p.s If you don't like proper object orientation and don't want to use "this", please at least make the helper method static O:)

Comment: Yes I think building the indent with indent+"\t" is much better but I wanted to frame this code this way primarily to should how depth correlated properties should/could be calculated.

Comment: But it could be so short! O:) 
`public void toStringRec(String indent, StringBuilder result) {
    result.append('\n').append(indent).append(node.val);
    for (Node sucessor : successors) {
      toStringRec(sucessor, indent + '\t', result);
    }
}`

Comment: Nice way to approach, I didn't thought about auxiliar function, I was trying to use just one function and it was too complex.